# How to disable frequently visited items and favorites under the address bar in Safari 8?

Tags: safari, macos, preferences

I want to remove the following frequently visited items and favorites under the address bar in Safari 8. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to **Safari Preferences** → **Search** and disable **Show Favourites**.

Answer (score 17):

You can actually remove "Frequently Visited" without disabling "Favorites" now by right clicking the background of the "New Tab" page. I did this in Safari 10, not sure if this works in Safari 9.

1. Settings -> General -> New tabs open with: Favorites
2. Open a new tab
3. Right click on the background
4. Uncheck "Show Frequently Visited Sites"

This setting in the "new tab" page is now also reflected in the URL bar.

Answer (score 0):

To remove Frequently Visited items, just simply click on the icon, hold and drag it out of the Window.

Do this for each item you wish to dismiss.

Done.

Comment: It works, but then you would also delete it.

Comment: This is in fact perfect. I had the problem that I delete some items, but after some time, they come back. In the way you said, it's done well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and go to safari then find frequently visited items slide left and it will be turned off there you go

Answer (score -3):

Click and drag to trash - that worked for me (Yosemite)

Answer (score -5):

You cannot disable the frequently visited annoyance. Yes, you can manually remove sites from it, but the annoyance is turned on by default and cannot be turned off, so sites will always continue to appear there.

Comment: this is incorrect, the accepted answer successfully hides the favorites